# How can I fix Webpack related error: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm using webpack, which, if I understand correctly, doesn't support native webworker syntax, so I'm trying to use the `worker-loader` npm module, but I'm getting a weird error.

The module can be found [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader).

My webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/build",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    watch: true,
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.worker\.js$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'worker-loader'
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

My code triggering the error:

```
import Worker from '../workers/sim.js';

class Synapse {
  // ...
}

module.exports = Synapse;
```

Error:

```
Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'?
```

which points to `module.exports = Synapse`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll get this error when mixing the CommonJS `module.exports` with ES Modules. You'll have to change `module.exports` to its ES Module counterpart `export default`:

```
import Worker from '../workers/sim.js';

class Synapse {
  // ...
}

export default Synapse; // ES Module syntax
```

Comment: I notice then I have to use `import` rather than `require` to retreive that module, then in turn other files that now mix commonJS `require` syntax and the `import` syntax break, so would it be correct to say that using `import` in this one case creates a chain reaction essentially forcing me to change all `require` calls in my project to `import`?

Comment: As of Babel 6, the behavior of `default export` changed, so that you need to use the following syntax: `require("./Synapse").default` as opposed to `require("./Synapse")`. Luckily, there is a Babel plugin that can bring the old behavior back, which is useful if you have many modules that use the older syntax: https://github.com/59naga/babel-plugin-add-module-exports . The other alternative is, as you mentioned, to change your `require` calls to ES Module `import`s

Answer (score -1):

You are doing import and export in the same file which is not allowed by webpack
better to do like this

```
const {Worker} = require('../workers/sim.js');

class Synapse {
  // ...
}

module.exports = {Synapse};
```

Comment: Do you understand that it's often done by npm modules authors, so the man doesn't do export himself. Just tried to import module which is already written like that. And it could be solved differently, but your answer is completely waste of your and other people time.